# How to Run Rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have been working on installing Rails. However, I am ending up with 2.2.3 and I need 2.3.8.

What I did was I installed ruby via:

```
apt-get install ruby build-essential #installed 1.8.7

apt-get install rubygems #installed 1.3.6

gem install rails-v2.3.8
```

I tried to run this but it didn't work. Ubuntu didn't know the command, 'rails' in `rails new blog`.

I tried to remedy this by installing rails, not via `gem` but by `apt-get`:

```
apt-get install rails
```

The version installed was rails 2.2.3

What should I be doing to install Rails 2.3.8?

Comment: if this is a development machine, take a look at [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). The problems you experienced will be taken care of for you. And much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gem install rails -v 2.3.8 should do it. Rails 2 makes a project like "rails name_of_project", without the new keyword. Do a "gem list" to check whether Rails 2.3.8 is installed. If it is, it may be that rails is not in your path.

Edit:

> I think that it would work if you add
>   "export
>   PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH" to
>   your ~/.bashrc. I can't really verify
>   because i work on mac os, but i think
>   it would. Else, try to execute a "find /
>   -name "rails" to locate it and add that to your path.

Comment: how do I add rais in my path. I have rails 2.3.8 in the gem list.

Comment: I think that it would work if you add "export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH" to your ~/.bashrc. I can't really verify because i work on mac os, but i think it would. Else, try to execute a "find -name / "*rails*" to locate it and add that to your path.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me modifying your answer. I just added your comment above.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Ruby Version Manager](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) and change version what you want.

Comment: +1 I had a problem with ubuntu and reinstalled. I'm now using rvm and am very very much happier